# Netflow data from Apple Airport?

Tags: airport

I am interested in getting netflow data from an apple airport. Netflow is a Cisco and internet standard that is used in network monitoring. My airport extreme supports SNMP and I use that for monitoring ,but netflow would give me a list of hosts. Any idea how to get this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst an AirPort Extreme does support SNMP as you mentioned, **they do not export Netflow data** (unless something has changed recently).

Answer (score 1):

I'm collecting netflow data from my Airport Express. I have an OpenBSD machine acting as the router for my AIRPORT VLAN (one of very many VLANs) and use the following in `pf.conf` (it collects pflow data for all passed packets):

```
set state-defaults pflow

# AIRPORT is the "descr" for the associated VLAN interface
pass in  on AIRPORT     all label "AIRPORT in"
pass out on AIRPORT     all label "AIRPORT out"
```

Send the collected pflow data to your netflow server on port 12345 on host 10.100.5.2:

```
# cat hostname.pflow0
flowsrc 10.100.5.1 flowdst 10.100.5.2:12345
```

Just setup a small little OpenBSD machine to handle your internal network routing and that's all there is to it. If you setup a VLAN trunk on an OpenBSD physical interface and tag all associated VLANs on the connected switch port then you're good to go.